# sql calculate date from column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I need a bit of advice with the following question which reads as follows:
Provide the sql that will determine the length of employment for each employee. For each employee display lastname and calulate number of years between today and the date on which the employee was hired. Label the column 'YEARS'

[image]

Im not sure how to approach this, should I use the datediff() function? Can I do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HIRE_DATE,'2014-09-29') AS DiffDate
```

Also how do I format DiffDate then that the output will only be years?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as

```
SELECT LastName, DATEDIFF('day',HIRE_DATE,'2014-09-29') AS DiffDate from TableName
```

I am assuming that Table contains LastName column.

[**Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Thanks AMIT I assume 'day' contains the year? in DATEDIFF()

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `DATEDIFF` could be found here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, HIRE_DATE,'2014-09-29') AS DiffDate 
From yourtable
```